# OpenMP in visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, openmp

I am going to start parallel programming using OpenMP.

I want to use OpenMP in Visual Studio. My visual Studio is 2010 ultimate trial edition. Is OpenMP available in this version?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use OpenMP (2.0 Standard) in Visual Studio 2010.  For details, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

However, if you're targeting Windows alone, you may also want to look at the [Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx).  It adds a huge library of very useful options for adding concurrency to an application.  For details on what this adds, see the [MSDN Comparison page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998048.aspx#openmp).

Comment: Thanks sir. could you tell me How to get start with OpenMP on Visual Studio???

Comment: @user642564 The first link, above, discusses what's involved.  For the most part, just compile with `/openmp`, include what you want, and it just works.  For an example, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z19s8e0.aspx